# How to create custom exception for loop handling

Tags: c#

I'm beginner in c# and I want to create custom exception and handle for loop with this exception
my code is

```
     static employees[] employee = new employees[3];

       for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1- id  2- Seclevel 3- salary 4- hired day 5- hired month 6- hired month 7- hired year 8-gender");
                        employee[i].id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        employee[i].hired.hday = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        employee[i].hired.hmonth = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        employee[i].hired.hyear = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        employee[i].salary = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        employee[i].secl = (securitylevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(securitylevel), Console.ReadLine());
                        employee[i].gen = (gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(gender), Console.ReadLine());

                    }
                    catch (CustomExc ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                }
```

My custom exception

```
 public class CustomExc : Exception {

        public CustomExc(): base(String.Format("Invalid input data"))
        {

        }

    }
```

for example i want output when user enter string values in int "Invalid input data"
My code doesn't work ..
exception work for me but custom didn't .. i don't know the reason

Comment: Where are you throwing `CustomExc`... can't catch what is not thrown.

Comment: Where in your code are you throwing a CustomExc?  I do not see it.  So, you cannot catch something you are not throwing

Comment: throw new CustomExc(); right ? but when i should write that? didn't work when i put this line in the end of for loop

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want your code to throw `CustomExc` if there's a problem reading data from the user that causes some *other* exception to be thrown?

Comment: @EdPlunkett as u said i want to throw customexc when user input is invalid data type

Comment: This really stinks of bad design... Why not simply check the validity of input(s), why are you letting the resource heavy `try/catch` handle simple validation?

Comment: @maccettura it's just test i need to test custom exception into for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any code that throws your custom exception.

If you want to throw your exception when the user inputs a string that can't be parsed as a number/enum/whatever, this is what you want:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 1- id  2- Seclevel 3- salary 4- hired day 5- hired month 6- hired month 7- hired year 8-gender");
    employee[i].id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].hired.hday = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].hired.hmonth = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].hired.hyear = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].salary = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].secl = (securitylevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(securitylevel), Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].gen = (gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(gender), Console.ReadLine());

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new CustomExc();
}
```

But then who catches `CustomExc`? Who watches the tailor's trousers, as the Romans so shrewdly wondered?

The following code may be what you really want. It's not clear to me that you really need to define your own exception type at all. This approach has the added benefit of preserving the original exception message, which may tell the user something useful about what he did wrong.

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 1- id  2- Seclevel 3- salary 4- hired day 5- hired month 6- hired month 7- hired year 8-gender");
    employee[i].id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].hired.hday = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].hired.hmonth = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].hired.hyear = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].salary = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].secl = (securitylevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(securitylevel), Console.ReadLine());
    employee[i].gen = (gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(gender), Console.ReadLine());

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Invalid input: {ex.Message}.");
}
```

### Update: Try/Catch

When you have a try/catch, you are guessing that the code inside the **try** block might throw an exception. If that does happen, the **catch** block receives the exception that gets thrown in the **try** block. You can also tell it what *kind* of exception you want to catch.

This one will catch `Exception`, or any subclass of `Exception`. That means *any* exception, because they all inherit from `Exception`:

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
```

This one will catch `CustomExc` -- *or any subclass* of `CustomExc`

```
} catch (CustomExc ex) {
```

You can also write this:

```
try {
    //  Various stuff
} catch (CustomExc ex1) {
    //  Special handling for CustomExc
} catch (NullReferenceException ex2) {
    //  Special handling for null references
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //  General handling any other exception
}
```

The *first* catch block that applies will be executed. The others won't be.

You could wrap a try/catch like that around the outside of your whole Main method, and do special handling for `CustomExc` and other handling for other errors. If you are going to throw `CustomExc`, you would do that. If you throw an exception, and you want to catch it, you have to make sure the code that throws it is executed inside a `try` block.

Or you could just print the error like in my second version of your code.

It's relatively uncommon to write custom exceptions, and quite uncommon in small programs. However, if your teacher tells you to write one, then of course you must.

But in the above code, the parse methods don't throw `CustomExc` because they've never heard of it. And when I throw `CustomExc` in the `catch` block, *that's not inside any `try` block at all*, so nothing catches that exception.

Comment: works for me but still crash .. only print my message

Comment: Right. That's why I asked where `CustomExc` is being caught. If an exception is thrown and never caught, the program will crash. That is the purpose of exceptions.

Comment: customexc caught when user input is another data type for example when user enter string in id (int) how can i do this ?

Comment: No, `CustomExc` is not caught at all. It is only thrown. Throw is not catch. Take another look at the code: It's thrown but it is never caught.

Comment: Playing catch is no fun if you are throwing and no one is there to _catch_ it...

Comment: @maccettura Depends what you're throwing, and at whom.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i'm sorry but i'm still beginner can u help me to make my code work ?

Comment: @Yasmeen EdPlunkett has given you everything you need to fix your problem.  The code that calls this input gathering routine, needs to wrap that call in a try/catch, that catch is where you will _catch_ the `CustomExc`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ty ed for your help and sorry for bothering you

Comment: @Yasmeen See my update about how exception handling works. I think you're having trouble understanding how exceptions work and what they're good for. If my explanation doesn't make sense (which is often the case), MSDN has some articles: [here's one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [here's another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/).

Comment: @EdPlunkett i know that exception will handle this but i want to use my own custom exception and i don't know how i can do that

Comment: @Yasmeen You would put a try/catch around the outside of your whole Main method. If you throw an exception, and you want to catch it, you have to make sure the code that throws it is inside a **try** block.

Comment: can i see how can i catch my exception ? any examples ?

Comment: @Yasmeen You already know how to write a try/catch block. Write a bigger one that contains your input loop. Read the MSDN articles I linked a few comments ago.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given the basic answer, but I'll repeat it here: If you want to throw a custom exception, then you can just throw it from your `catch` (and hopefully the caller of this method will know what to do with it):

```
catch
{
    throw new CustomException("There was an error parsing user input");
}
```

But it would be better to throw specific exceptions as they occur. Most likely your exceptions are converting the user-entered strings to ints or doubles or enums. Instead of using `Parse`, you can use `TryParse`, which will return `true` if the conversion was successful and will set the out parameter to the converted value:

```
int input;
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
{
    employee[i].hired.hday = input;
}
else
{
    throw new CustomException("Hired day input was not a valid integer");
}
```

Then, since you need to do this more than once, you can put the functionality in a custom method, and you can put it in a loop that forces the user to enter valid data:

```
public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int input;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input));

    return input;
}

public static double GetDoubleFromUser(string prompt)
{
    double input;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input));

    return input;
}

public static T GetEnumFromUser<T>(string prompt) where T : struct
{
    T input;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), false, out input));

    return input;
}
```

Now your user CANNOT enter data of the wrong type:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter employee information:");
employee[i].id = GetIntFromUser("Enter Id: ");
employee[i].hired.hday = GetIntFromUser("Enter hired day: ");
employee[i].hired.hmonth = GetIntFromUser("Enter hired month: ");
employee[i].hired.hyear = GetIntFromUser("Enter hired year: ");
employee[i].salary = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter salary: ");
employee[i].secl = GetEnumFromUser<securitylevel>("Enter Security Level: ");
employee[i].gen = GetEnumFromUser<gender>("Enter gender: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for each parameter if value is not valid as per your business logic you can throw exception using `throw new CustomExp()` like:

```
int Id =0;
bool IsValid = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out Id);
if(!IsValid)
{
  throw new CustomExp();
}
else
{
  employee[i].id = Id;
}
```

The above is an example for `id` property, something similar you would need to do for this.

But you should not be throwing exception for this, you can notify on UI to re-enter a valid value instead of throwing a Custom Exception and then catching it.

If this is just for learning purpose about Custom Exception, then it should be fine, otherwise there are better approaches to deal this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so should i make every line in separated if statements ?

Comment: if you want to throw exception in case input is invalid for any of those. then yes.